# Distance between two cells in a 2D matrix

Tags: c++, matrix, euclidean-distance

I have a 2D matrix represented as a vector of values, an index representing the first cell and a pair of coordinate representing the second cell.

```
vector<double> matrix;
auto index = 10;

auto x1 = index % width;
auto y1 = index / width;
auto x2 = ...
auto y2 = ...
```

I need to find the distance between these two cells, where the distance is equals to 1 for the first "ring" of the 8 neighbor cells, 2 for the second ring, and so on.

Is there a way faster than the euclidean distance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is something like a modified [Manhattan Distance](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCgQFjABahUKEwjVgpyIj_LIAhViHqYKHXuXBYo&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wiktionary.org%2Fwiki%2FManhattan_distance&usg=AFQjCNGcRgWLe3s18w0gCHTcuwvjqHrKYg&sig2=sU_sa35FF0bbSwm3nhns7Q&bvm=bv.106379543,d.dGY). I think there may be a specific name for your use case, but I don't know it. Anyway, this is how I'd do it.

Suppose the two points are `x` rows away and `y` columns away. Then `x+y` is the Manhattan Distance. But in your case, diagonal movements are also allowed. So, if you moved diagonally towards the point initially, you'd cover the smaller of `x` and `y`, with some amount remaining in the other. You can then move horizontally/vertically to cover the remaining distance. Hence, the distance by your metric would be `max(x,y)`.

Given points `(x1,y1)` and `(x2,y2)`, the answer would be `max(|x1-x2|,|y1-y2|)`